# Why can't the program find manually appended '#' (hashtags) in a string?

Tags: c++, string, find

When I run this program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cerr << "[ERR] usage: " << argv[0] << " expression" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string pExpression = argv[1];

    size_t stringLength = pExpression.length();

    if (pExpression[stringLength - 1] != '#') //If there is no hashtag at the end, append one
        pExpression += '#';

    cout << "Search for '#' in '" << pExpression << "'..." << endl;

    bool found = false;

    for (size_t i = 0;i < stringLength;i++)
    {
        if (pExpression[i] == '#')
            found = true;
    }

    cout << ((found) ? "String contains '#'" : "String doesn't contain '#'") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I try to check, if there is a hashtag at the end. When there is none, I append one.

However, if I check for it, my programm "can't find" it.

Here is an example on what I mean:

[image]

Comment: That's not a hashtag, it's the hash (or pound, or number, or various other names) character. "Hashtag" is a term for a label (tag) that begins with that character occurring in various "social" media.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't increase `stringLength` after you add the `#`. So the `for` loop stops right in front of it.

Comment: Use [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead of a manual loop.